# In Yemenite Nusach, what are the differences between Shami and Baladi?

Tags: synagogue, nuschaot, yemenite-temani

In my curiosity of possibly attending a Yemenite minyan on Shabbat, I viewed [this directory](http://jewishyemenites.com/JY_synog.html) of Yemenite congregations in the U.S.

The last column lists 2 nuscha'ot - Shami and Baladi

As I am a neophyte in this area, can someone explain what these terms mean and highlight or summarize some of the differences in prayers, specifically Shabbat prayers or any other differences?

Specifically, if I were to enter one of these shuls on Shabbat, what idfferences would I notice? I am Ashkenazi Orthodox and daven Nusach Ashkenaz. My Hebrew is fluent. Entering this type of shul is a new experience for me. Would I have an easier time "adjusting" or feeling comfortable / following along in one nusach of the other one?

For the curious, I may try the Ymenite minyan in Boca Raton in a few weeks, as I may be in that area visiting someone.

Comment: FWIW, Sham is a region of the Middle East including Syria, Lebanon, Jordan and other nearby countries. Baladi is a term in Arabic which essentially means traditional. That would go nicely with Yaacov Deane's answer below for Baladi, but I don't know what connection Sham has to the Yemenite _nusach_.

Comment: balad means country. baladi means my country. baladi nosah means nosah of my country ie teimon. nosah shaami is called shaami because it comes from shaam mixed with traditional teimoni nosah. it incorporates the qabbalisitic nosah of the north which came to teimon through zakhariyo al dhahiri. he met with beith yoseif and brought these books to teimon. unfortunately so. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zechariah_Dhahiri

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob Balad does mean country, but baladi also means traditional or rustic (domestic). Here the _i_ suffix doesn't mean "mine" but rather it turns a noun into an adjective (like _temani_)

Comment: @Daniel http://puu.sh/mABb4/c1e1672b28.png

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob As I said, _baladi_ does indeed mean "my country." But it also means _traditional_ (and this is the common usage of the word). I am rather sure that this is the usage here. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baladi)

Comment: i wasnt arguing it didnt mean traditional. my country and traditional are pretty much the same thing. but maybe you wanted to make it more specific or something idk. its ok though we got the point lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Shami nusach is accepting concepts brought from the Ari z"l. The Baladi nusach follows the older Yemenite tradition.

For many Jews from Yemen, they do not want any innovations from their older tradition. Their tradition is that their community originated from soldiers sent to Yemen by Shlomo HaMelech. When the Rambam moved to Egypt from Spain he had contact with the Yemenite community and helped to preserve their practice. That is the source of the Baladi nusach.

The Shami nusach has a relationship to Rabbi Shalom Sharabi who was a Yemenite Kabbalist who followed the Ari z"l.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yemenite_Jews

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that the Shami use the almost the same "nusach" like the sepharadic Jews. While Baladi have a very different Nusach mainly they have a shorter "nusach". In any case both are pretty different from all the rest especially due to the accent and the special ways to read the Torah.

Sorry is the answer is not elaborated due to the hour.

שבוע טוב!